# Job Control/background process (using ampersand) in .ebextensions config commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, background-process, elastic-beanstalk

Take for example the following .config file in .ebextensions/

```
container_commands: 
  000_run_queue_daemon: 
    command: "nohup php artisan queue:work --daemon &"
    test: "ps -ef | grep artisan | grep -v grep > /dev/null || echo 1"
```

If the daemon is not already running, start a queue worker. The queue worker daemon runs forever (by design) and therefore needs to be run as a background process.

The ampersand seems to have no effect and tailing cfn-init.log just halts at

```
2014-09-15 00:24:53,921 [DEBUG] Running test for command 000_run_queue_daemon
2014-09-15 00:24:53,929 [DEBUG] Test command output: 1

2014-09-15 00:24:53,929 [DEBUG] Test for command 000_run_queue_daemon passed
```

This then stays as such until the EB process times out and it gives up with the deployment.

How can I make this run as a background process?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to make this work I had to run the command from a file using the post deployment hooks

```
commands:
  create_post_dir:
    command: "mkdir /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post"
    ignoreErrors: true

files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_restart_workers.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      nohup php /var/app/current/artisan queue:work --daemon >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Hi, looks like you have solved your own case. Can you mark this answer as accepted?

Comment: This worked beautifully for me.

Comment: I'm having trouble with this. It seems like the hook works and runs `queue:work` but it does not use the environment variables set in the EB configuration page. The result is that I get the error `Predis\Connection\ConnectionException` with the message `Connection refused [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]`, since it is using the default values. Googling seems to indicate that the environment variables are not available in hooks.

Comment: @Marius there are a few ways you can do this. Off the top of my head i think you can just put `source /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars` into your restart_workers_99.sh file at the top and it'll  load the env vars in. Another option which I believe works (again if i remember correctly) is change commands: to container_commands: as container commands run with the env vars set

Comment: This may have also changed on newer versions of elastic beanstalk that use amazon linux 2

Comment: `sudo /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment --output YAML|JSON|??` may help you too

Comment: What you can do is add your environment variables in your file e.g. `export ACCESS_KEY_ID_S3_STATIC="XXXX"` above the nohup command.